# Texture issue and Light too weak

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I tried to display this model : http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/sprite-bottle-91563.html

The problem is that the texture is not where it should be, and the light is weirdly too weak. It only displays well if i put like 10 AmbientLight.

[What it looks like / What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA6L1.jpg) (on the first screenshot, we don't see the texture. that's because there's only one directionnal light like below)

Could you help me ?

Code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
light.position.set( 10, 10, 10 );
scene.add( light );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 0.1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

cube.position.z = -2
scene.add( cube );

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath( 'spriteModel/' );
var url = "SpriteBottle.mtl";
mtlLoader.load( url, function( materials ) {
    materials.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( 'spriteModel/' );
    objLoader.load( 'SpriteBottle.obj', function ( object ) {
        scene.add( object );
    }, function() {}, function() {} );
});

camera.position.z = 5;
var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper( 5 );
scene.add( axisHelper );
var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
        camera.rotation.z += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

Comment: Try to add ambiant light as well.

Comment: 'materials' object comes from mtl . Edit mtl file if you wanna change your look.